# Why isn’t it possible to use a CNAME alias to Google Storage with HTTPS?

Tags: http, redirect, https, dns, cname

The Google Storage documentation page states that `You can use a CNAME redirect only with HTTP, not with HTTPS.` But I cannot see any reason for that. Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: I guess it's for additional security. I don't know who enforces this though - the DNS, the browser, or Google

Comment: In addition to the answer below about multi-domain certs, it is also possible if you are using a service such as Cloudflare, which besides providing a DNS service also acts as a HTTP(S) proxy and terminates (decrypts) the SSL connection from the client before making its own (either HTTP or HTTPS - depending on settings) connection to the server and forwarding the content.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Assume you have a CNAME record:

```
travel-maps.example.com CNAME c.commondatastorage.googleapis.com.
```

Browser resolves name `travel-maps.example.com` and gets IP for `c.commondatastorage.googleapis.com`, then connects to port 443 of this address.

Server with this IP couldn't possibly[1] have proper certificate for `travel-maps.example.com` (and all other domain names with CNAME records like this). Only `example.com` domain owner could get a trusted cert for his own domain.

[1] Unless you uploaded the certificate to the CDN network which is a common feature nowadays.

Comment: as Apache can distinguish what domain the browser is surfing on (with VirtualHost), why can’t it just serve the appropriate certificate for each one?

Comment: Google - owner of googleapis.com don't have cert for travel-maps.example.com

Comment: With that CNAME record browser connects to google IP, not your's apache.

Comment: This answer makes it clear why a CNAME from one owner to another wouldn't work with HTTPS, but not why a CNAME to another record owned by the same wouldn't. Could you describe that, please?

Comment: @kojiro If the server certificate will match CNAME record (travel-maps.example.com in this case) SSL will be working fine.

Comment: But why couldn't I give Google a copy of my certificate?  Almost every site hosting supports it, [including App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl).

Answer (score 39):

It **is possible**!

There could be many domains attached to one SSL certificate.

> ASSUME  travel-maps.example.com CNAME c.commondatastorage.googleapis.com.

When both domains are in the SSL cert list, your CNAME can redirect with HTTPS.

---

[image: Demo]

This is how CDN service providers such as Incapsula work with HTTPS.
They just create a "Multi-domain" SSL cert for you.

You may check a demo cert-info in this site.
https://www.incapsula.com/

---

Any way, this kind of SSL cert is for business use in most case and are generally pretty expensive.

Comment: so, if a CDN provides service to a HTTPS-site foo, does it mean that I am no longer using the certificate provided by foo, and instead relying on the CDN's one?

Comment: No, you data still needs to be encrypted between your server and CDN server. Theoretically, you may use a self-signed ssl cert for your server.