# How to register the aws elasticsearch service on route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-route53

I'm using Elasticsearch service on AWS

Creating an Elasticsearch instance makes endpoint name like https://search-class101-elasticsearch-XXXX.ap-region.es.amazonaws.com,

but i want Elasticsearch domain like https://elasticsearch.mydomain.com/ I'm trying to.

i'm already tried register as a CNAME on route 53

it returns error "invalid certificate" because different domain name

then, can i rename(alias) doamin with https for aws elasticsearch?

Comment: You can't CNAME two https endpoint to one another, CNAME only works for HTTP - Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294215/why-isn-t-it-possible-to-use-a-cname-redirect-with-https

Comment: There's an workaround described here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/set-access-control-for-amazon-elasticsearch-service/

Comment: I did with route53 plus LB.  I add an entry in route53 and then on host-based routing I redirect the request to ELK.

Comment: @Adiii So more or less you added a proxy before ES. That seems silly because ES has its own ELB before it.

Comment: Yes but that was only for kibana endpoints as hard to remember for user but for applications elk own end point should work

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to create a custom endpoint for AWS Elasticsearch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-customendpoint.html.

After this has been setup, you can create a *Route53* A record for the IP addresses of your custom Elasticsearch endpoint.

[image]

To set it up, select your Elasticsearch domain and click "Edit Domain". There you have the possibility to provide the hostname and the certificate for it.