# How to reroute s3 static website from HTTP to HTTPS without CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

We have created self-hosted site within S3 as static websites in an AWS account.

example.com is one of those sites which has Route53 CNAME records (in different AWS account) which allows clients to access the site via HTTP (http//example.com).

The client is having issues currently due to this site being not secure, so we need to move this to HTTPS. Cloudfront is an option, the Route53 host (example.com) is not in the same account as S3 static site (which is in other AWS account), so CloudFront is unable to authenticate.

Please help in providing the options to re-routing to HTTPS from HTTP.

Comment: Maybe this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294215/why-isn-t-it-possible-to-use-a-cname-redirect-with-https  someone ther esays you can do this.

Comment: @Winston none of those answers apply to S3.

Comment: You have to place something in front of S3. That means using a CDN. You can use CloudFront or Cloudflare or similar. Your comment about CloudFront "not being able to authenticate" sounds like the actual question you should be posting.